# NextJS 13 drizzele query is not executing

Tags: reactjs, database, vercel, next.js13

here is my code i am working on cart functionality but drizzele query is not being executed

```
import { eq } from "drizzle-orm";
import { filterProductName } from "../datafetching";
import { db, table } from "@/app/drizzle/schema";
import User_id from "./servercomp";
import { product } from "@/sanity/product";

const Drizzelefetch = async () => {
  try {
    const fun = async () => {
      const usr_id = await User_id();
      console.log(`usr_id${usr_id}`);
      const query = await db
        .select()
        .from(table)
        .where(eq(table.user_id, `${usr_id}`));
      return query;
    };
    const query = await fun();
    return query;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Nothing is in vercel DB");
    return [];
  }
};
export default Drizzelefetch;
```

const usr_id = await User_id();
console.log(`usr_id${usr_id}`);
after these 2 line the query dont executes during writing of code when i was not rendering anything during coding phases it always worked but now after these lines catch runs and user_id value shows string and i checked the vercel db has the data with the user_id but the query dont executes
this code is called by this function

```
export const Datafetch = async () => {
  const query = await Drizzelefetch();
  console.log(`query response${query}`);

  let product_id;
  let quantity;
  let queryobj: queryObj = {
    product_id,
    quantity,
  };

  try {
    if (Object.keys(query).length > 0) {
      const data: queryObj[] = query.map((query: any) => {
        queryobj.product_id = query.product_id;
        queryobj.quantity = query.quantity;
        return { product_id: queryobj.product_id, quantity: queryobj.quantity };
      });

      const summedQuantities: { product_id: string; quantity: number }[] =
        Object.values(
          data.reduce(
            (
              result: {
                [product_id: string]: { product_id: string; quantity: number };
              },
              { product_id, quantity }
            ) => {
              if (result[product_id]) {
                result[product_id].quantity += quantity;
              } else {
                result[product_id] = { product_id, quantity };
              }
              return result;
            },
            {}
          )
        );

      try {
        const updatedData: Product[] = await Promise.all(
          summedQuantities.map(async (item) => {
            const fetchdata = await filterProductName(item.product_id);
            return {
              _id: item.product_id,
              name: fetchdata.name,
              price: fetchdata.price,
              type: fetchdata.type,
              quantity: item.quantity,
              image: fetchdata.image,
            };
          })
        );

        return updatedData;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("There is no data regarding this product in sanity");
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Nothing in cart");
      return [];
    }
  } catch (error) {
    log(error);
  }
};
```

above code return data here in this component i render the data
code

```
const CartItems = async () => {
  const data = await Datafetch();
  return (
    <div
      id="outer-main"
      className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center lg:my-16 lg:mx-32 md:flex md:flex-row  lg:flex lg:justify-center lg:items-center gap-10  p-[3rem]"
    >
     {         ***all client related code***            }
     </div>
  );
};

export default CartItems;
```

this above is called in another funtion which is called in Page component to show all cart items

Comment: in developer menu on console when process executes the output occurs as                                quantity is 4,  
4,  usr_id9a6dcf47-d605-41fe-a914-97d76423012a, 
Nothing is in vercel DB( drizilefetch.tsx:21:12), 
query response datafetch.tsx:28:10
Nothing in cart === so try is not executing properly